# Nmap scanning ip's from a range with port 3389 open

Tags: nmap

I need a command for this, with as output only ip's with port 3389 open.

Example: #nmap -p3389 -P0 -sS 192.168.2.0/24

I've read this somewhere, this works but it doesn't give a list of ip's with that port open.

I just started today with nmap, hope you will understand

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider

```
nmap -p3389 -P0 -sS 192.168.2.0/24 | grep "scan" | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1
```

I know that this doesn't use exclusively nmap, but it does output only the ip numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo nmap -p3389 -P0 -oG - -sS 192.68.2.0/24 | \
    sed -n 's/.* \([0-9\.]\{7,\}\).*\/open\/.*/\1/p'
```